# Append length of string for each string in list

Tags: python

**Input**

```
strlist = ['test', 'string']
```

**Desired output:**

```
strlist = [('test', 4), ('string', 6)]
```

Attempt 1:

```
def add_len(strlist):
    for i, c in enumerate(strlist):
        strlist += str(len(strlist))
    return strlist
```

Attempt 2:

```
def add_len(strlist):
    for c in strlist:
        c += " " + str(len(c))
    return strlist
```

I realise I have the following issues:

- **Attempt 1:** This results in an infinite loop, as the code keeps adding onto the list.
- **Attempt 2:** This does not add the value to the string, however, when I do, I get the infinite loop issue from #1.

I believe I need to evaluate the number of elements in the list first and implement a while statement, but not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: a trivial `[(s, len(s)) for s in strlist]` should do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension like this.

```
def add_len(strlist):
    return [(s, len(s)) for s in strlist]
```

Or expanded,

```
def add_len(strlist):
    new_list = []
    for s in strlist:
        new_list.append((s, len(s)))
    return new_list
```

In the expanded form we can see the steps it's going through a bit more clearly.

1. Create list `new_list` to put your strings and lengths into.
2. Iterate over each string in `strlist`.
3. For each string, append the string and its length to `new_list`.
4. Return `new_list`.

Of course, both of these gives you your desired output:

```
[('test', 4), ('string', 6)]
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a list comprehension:

```
strlist = ['test', 'string']

def add_len(strlist):
    return [(s, len(s)) for s in strlist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map()`:

```
>>> strlist
['test', 'string']

>>> list(map(lambda x: (x, len(x)), strlist))
[('test', 4), ('string', 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, c in enumerate(strlist)
```

The `i` is the index of the element in the string list, and the `c` the value of the element. And you keep on appending the results in place (`strlist`), so that the `strlist` keeps growing.

While the second attempt won't output your desired results. The result will be `strlist = ['test 4', 'string 6']`. Every single element is not made up of `tuple`.

Meanwhile both the two attempts modify `strlist` in place, which will bring in potential issues (affect other attributes/parameters that refer to `strlist`).

A better solution for this is using list comprehension.

```
strlist = ['test', 'string']
new_strlist = [(s, len(s)) for s in strlist]
```